# Identify regex is applied to html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to identify the regex that has been applied to the HTML element using Jquery.

**Note: I am working on Asp.net MVC application. HTML elements are already there on CSHTML page, I am just binding events in functions.**

E.g.
I am binding events to the HTML control dynamically as follows.

```
CreateTextBox("txtUserPassword","/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/", "Wrong input");
```

A function looks like following.

```
function CreateTextBox(id, RegexText, ValidationMessage)
{
    CreateValidation(id, RegexText, ValidationMessage);
}
```

Now, when I send data of the textbox to server side using Ajax, first I want to know which regular expression is used for particular control as all controls are being created dynamically.

So, is it possible to set custom property **(it should not be visible in the dom like an attribute, also not like data in Jquery)** of the text box control?

So we can access jquery property it like following.

```
var ControlRegex = $("#txtUserPassword").("CustomRegex");
```

**So, variable ControlRegex will be *"/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/"**

Any guesses??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just compare the regex values:

```
const a = "/abc/"
const b = "/def/"

function isRegExA(regEx) {
    return regEx === a
}

console.log(isRegExA(a)) //true
console.log(isRegExA(b)) //false
```